# How to connect to Realm from aws lambda node

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, realm

I am trying to connect to a Realm instance from an aws lambda (node) with the following code:

```
 await Realm.Sync.User.login('https://server.realm.io', 'username', 'password')
    .then((user) => {
        let config = user.createConfiguration();
        config.schema = [Schema];
        Realm.open(config).then((realm) => {
            //Do some cool stuff  });
```

The problem is it tries to create a directory **realm-object-server** when it logins. As we know the lambdas file system is read-only except for the tmp folder. Is there a way to tell realm to write this **realm-object-server** to the tmp folder or is there a way to login that doenst create a direcotry at all?
Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue using Realm from a Google Cloud Function. None of the Realm configuration options like `path` or `inMemory` seemed to have any effect. After much digging, the solution I found was to call `process.chdir('/tmp')` prior to opening the Realm. This changes the current NodeJS process's working directory as explained [in the NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory). This allowed me to open the realm successfully.

Comment: Thank you we had ended up running our realm on doccker containers but this is o much better .Thanks again